# How can I use 15 servos with arduino mega2560 without stepping down voltage?

Tags: arduino, motor, dc-motor, servo

How can I use 15 servos with arduino mega2560 without stepping down voltage?

because I want to control 15 servos by one board (arduino mega 2560).

Comment: mate, how do you intend to interface with the servos? You do not need to step down voltages..

Answer (score 3):

I think you haven't worked with servo motors yet. They requires external power to drive the motor(as they require high current which cannot be delivered by microcontoller)

Servo motors will have 3 pins

```
1. +V(recommended voltage for servomotor)

2.Controlsignal(pin from microcontroller output) 

3.gnd(common gnd).
```

Hence there will be no point of stepping down or up the power..

Comment: I would also hope they have some serious breakout/shield boards to deal with 15 connections, and have enough DIO pins spare

Comment: and software control of 15 servos will be extremely tricky, probably with a lot of jitter and error/issues for main code due to all the timers going off and ISRs being run etc.

Comment: Yes i do agree with that, but i had used 6 servomotors on a single microcontroller which didn't cause me any problem.

Comment: 15 is close to 3 times more than what you've tested with. Doesn't take much to break an MCU!